# mySQL trigger? causing Error Code: 1048 Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have seen similar questions asked but never seen an answer that works for me.  I have the following table and trigger definitions...

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS c_consumption.newRateHistory;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c_consumption.myrate;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c_consumption.myratehistory;

USE c_consumption;
    CREATE TABLE `myrate` (
    `consumerId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `durationType` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DAY',
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `itemId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.0,
    `quantityType` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'GALLON',
    `timePeriod` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE_RATE` 
    (`itemId` ASC, `consumerId` ASC)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=314 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


  CREATE TABLE `myratehistory` (
    `consumerId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `durationType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `itemId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `quantityType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CREATED',
    `timePeriod` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `timestamp` DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`, `consumerId`, `timestamp`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=314 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TRIGGER `newRateToHistory`
AFTER INSERT
ON myrate
FOR EACH ROW

  INSERT INTO myratehistory
  (
    consumerId,
    durationType,
    itemId,
    quantity,
    quantityType,
    status,
    timePeriod,
    timestamp
  )
    VALUES(
        new.consumerId,
        new.durationType,
        new.itemId,
        new.quantity,
        new.quantityType,
        'CREATED',
        new.timePeriod,
        now());
```

Note that consumerId CAN be null.

Next I run this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO c_consumption.myrate (          
    consumerId,
    durationType,
    itemId,
    quantity,
    quantityType,
    timePeriod)
VALUES(
    null,
    'DAY',
    'MyItem',
    1.0,
    'GALLON',
    1.0);
```

I get the following message:

```
Error Code: 1048 Column 'consumerId' cannot be null
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong but I do not know what it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConsumerId is part of the primary key.  No part of the primary key can be null.

Comment: Why is that?  null is a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, why mysql allows a null-able column as part of the primary key I don't know

```
CREATE TABLE `myratehistory` (
    [...]
    PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`, `consumerId`, `timestamp`)
```

Comment: Mysql treats NULLs as unique but I dont think it allows them in a Primary Key.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood me, what I meant was that it would have made more sense if the creation of the primary key would have failed due to the null-able column. Now it generates a nasty run-time error.

Comment: Agreed.  If it had given that error, I wouldn't have had to post something.  Though hopefully they will change this as null is valid and it would be very useful to have the consumerId as part of my key.

Comment: When a primary key is declared, the column(s) that from it become non nullable.  That is very standard across practically all dialects of SQL.

Comment: DB2 (LUW atleast) does not allow a primary key to be created on a null-able column.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL server is running in "strict" mode, which throws an error in case like yours are otherwise handled "gracefully" without strict mode.
As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, which is exactly the cause of your headache.

To change your server's mode, edit your `my.cnf` (or `my.ini` if you're running Windows) and set the mode to:

```
sql-mode=""
```

Then you must restart your mysql server like this:

```
service mysql reload
```

Or directly throw init.d process:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql reload
```

Hope it will help you.